# Self signed certificate React Native

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I try to import a self signed certificate (certificate.crt) in call API in React Native but every time, I have the same error :

```
Unable to resolve module `../certificate.crt`
```

I am using React Native with Redux and Redux Saga

```
import axios from "axios";

const casert = require("../certificate.crt");

const API_URL = "MY_IP_SERVER";

export function callGetApi(url, param) {
    return axios({
    method: "get",
    ca: casert,
    url: `${API_URL}${url}${param}`,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
}
```

The file tree is like this:

[image: Project file tree]

If someone has an idea how to include this self signed certificate because the API need it in the header to accept any requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `axios`, take a look at:

> [How can I make a HTTPS to the backend with a self-signed certificate?](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1185#issuecomment-367676835)

Do all of the steps and then you have something like this:

```jsx
  <Button onPress={
    ()=>{
      const x = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'https://api.realtycoast.io/',
        timeout: 10000,
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      });
    x.request({
      url: '/user/123'
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }>
    <Text>Axios Test</Text>
  </Button>
```

Comment: Thank you MohamadKh75 but I need to include the certificate in my request, on client side, to be accepted by the API as a "certify client" to do request on this API.

Answer (score -1):

I found a beginning of answer with this : https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1495

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "HTTPS://MY_IP_SERVER";

export function callGetApi(url, param) {
    return axios({
        method: "get",
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
            ca: fs.readFileSync("../certificate.crt"),
        }),
        url: `${API_URL}${url}${param}`,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
}
```

Know, the certificate is include but in my saga function, in directly go in the catch exception when I try to execute the API call

```
export function* loginRequest(payload) {

    yield takeEvery(authActions.LOGIN_REQUEST, function*(payload) {
        try {

            console.log("Email Saga : " + payload.email);
            let response = null;

            response = yield call(requestUUID, "account/uuid/email/", payload.email);
            const uuid = response.data.uuid;

            debugger;

            yield put({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS" });
        } catch (error) {
            debugger;
            yield put({ type: authActions.LOGIN_ERROR });
        }
    });
}
```